# Aurelia and Kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, aurelia

When using Kendo with AngularJS, it is possible (maybe preferred) to configure the components in your javascript via the `k-options` attribute

```
<input kendo-date-picker k-options="monthPickerConfig">
```

However with Aurelia it seems that the configuration is only available in the markup.

```
<input style="width: 100%;"
       ak-datetimepicker="k-value.two-way: today;
        k-widget.two-way: startDatePicker;
        k-parse-formats.bind: ['MM/dd/yyyy']"
        k-on-change.delegate="startChange()"/>
```

Is my understanding here correct, or is there a way to configure the widets via javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Aurelia KendoUI Bridge](https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-kendoui-bridge) wrapper, indeed the most documented way is configuring your Kendo components through the view. Like you mentioned something like:

```
<input id="monthpicker" 
    ak-datepicker="k-value.bind:'November 2011'; 
    k-start.bind:'year'; 
    k-depth.bind: 'year';
    k-format.bind:'MMMM yyyy';" 
    style="width: 100%" />
```

But I believe there is nothing stopping you from [referencing this element](http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#referencing-elements) in your view<>viewmodel:

```
<!-- simplified -->
<input id="monthpicker" view-model.ref="mypicker" />
```

... so you can configure it completely in your viewmodel:

```js
import 'kendo-ui/js/kendo.combobox';

export class App {
    private mypicker: kendo.ui.DatePicker;

    attached() {
        this.mypicker... // <-- set your config/options for Kendo here...
    }
}
```

Might be an alternative, right?